# Revert innerHTML to default after javascript event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, innerhtml, revert

I have an event listener that takes input from the user and replaces the default text "Your Username" with the user input.

```
<input type="text" class="search">
<div id="username">Your Username</div>

<script>
    var search = document.querySelector('.search');
    search.addEventListener('input', changeText);
    function changeText() {username.innerHTML = `${this.value}`}
</script>
```

If the user backspaces all input, I want the innerHTML of the div to revert to the default (i.e. "Your Username").  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the original HTML in initialization, then use it in the change listener if valye is an empty string:

```
var search = document.querySelector('.search');
var originalHTML = username.innerHTML;
search.addEventListener('input', changeText);
function changeText() {
  username.innerHTML =  this.value !== '' ? this.value : originalHTML; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I prefer this answer to the other two offered as innerHTML can be a whole big block of HTML and it saves me from having to type it all out again.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a conditional on your eventListener, if input value is null, something like this can do the trick:

```
<input type="text" class="search">
<div id="username">Your Username</div>

<script>
    var search = document.querySelector('.search');
    search.addEventListener('input', changeText);
    function changeText() {
        if(input.value == "") {
            username.innerHTML = "Your Username";
        } else {
            username.innerHTML = `${this.value}`
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your default text with || operator.

`` function changeText() {username.innerHTML = `${this.value || 'Your default value'}`} ``

This will set the text to the default value if this.value is null or undefined or empty.